# php Mail form sending not required text

Tags: php, forms, isset

I have a php mail form with a item that is not required to be written. 
This item has the variable $text, and every time a mail is sent, even if this item was not filled, a text in the body of the message will be sent.
This is the code for the body of the message:

```
■message
$text
```

and the message will look like this:

■message

Using "isset", I want to make a condition that only writes "message" text when $text is defined. As I am not familiar with php, I am doing something wrong..

```
$message = "message"; 

$text = isset($_POST[$message]) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST[$message]): "";

$message
$text
```

here is the original code:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
session_start();
if($_SESSION['input_flag']) {
    unset($_SESSION['input_flag']);
}else{
    header('location: /');
}

$path = realpath(dirname(__FILE__) . '') . "/../";
include_once($path.'app_config.php');
include($path.'libs/meta.php');


require('./jphpmailer.php');
$script = "index.php";
$gtime = time();
//$f_name = isset($_POST['f_name']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_name']): "";
$reg_name = isset($_POST['f_name']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_name']): "";
$f_tel = isset($_POST['f_tel']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_tel']): "";
//$f_mail = isset($_POST['f_mail']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_mail']): "";
$reg_email = isset($_POST['f_mail']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_mail']): "";
$text = isset($_POST['text']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['text']): "";
$f_model = isset($_POST['f_model']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_model']): "";
$f_request = isset($_POST['f_request']) ? htmlspecialchars($_POST['f_request']): "";
$f_select = '';



foreach ($_POST['select'] as $key => $value) {
$f_select .= $value.'';
}

$aMailto = array(
  "xxxx@xxx.com"
);
$from = "test@xxxx.com";
$fromname = 'test';
$subject1 = 'test';
$subject = 'test';
$entry_time = gmdate("Y/m/d H:i:s",time()+9*3600);
$entry_host = gethostbyaddr(getenv("REMOTE_ADDR"));
$entry_ua = getenv("HTTP_USER_AGENT");


$msgBody = "";
$msgBody .= "
■お名前
$reg_name

■お電話番号
$f_tel

■メールアドレス
$reg_email

■message
$text

■ご希望の連絡方法
$f_select

■ご希望の車種
$f_model

■お問い合わせ内容
$f_request
";



$msgBody


";


---------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------

$msgBody



mb_language("ja");
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

$fromname = "test";



$email1 = new JPHPmailer();
$email1->addTo($reg_email);
$email1->setFrom($from,$fromname);
$email1->setSubject($subject1);
$email1->setBody($body1);

//if($email1->send()) {};

//Anti spam advanced version 2 start: Don't send blank emails
if( $reg_name <> "" && $reg_email <> "" ) {

  //Anti spam advanced version 1 start: The preg_match() is there to make sure spammers can’t abuse your server by injecting extra fields (such as CC and BCC) into the header.
  if( $reg_email && !preg_match( "/[\r\n]/", $reg_email) ) {

    //Anti spam part1: the contact form start
    if($reg_url == ""){

        // then send the form to your email
      if($email1->Send()) {};
    } // otherwise, let the spammer think that they got their message through
    //Anti spam part1: the contact form end
  }//Anti spam advanced version 1 end
}//Anti spam advanced version 2 end: Don't send blank emails



//メール送信
$email = new JPHPmailer();
for($i = 0; $i < count($aMailto); $i++)
{
  $email->addTo($aMailto[$i]);
}
$email->setFrom($reg_email, $reg_name."様");
$email->setSubject($subject);
$email->setBody($body);

//if($email->Send()) {};

//Anti spam advanced version 2 start: Don't send blank emails
if( $reg_name <> "" && $reg_email <> "" ) {

  //Anti spam part1: the contact form start
  if($reg_url == ""){

      // then send the form to your email
    if($email->Send()) {};
  } // otherwise, let the spammer think that they got their message through
  //Anti spam part1: the contact form end
}//Anti spam advanced version 2 end: Don't send blank emails




?>
```

Comment: what are $message and $text doing in last lines?... please, share you entire code

Comment: I added the original code.